# Stop AJAX error from propagating to ajaxError

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following global AJAX error handler...

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (event, request, settings) {
   ...
});
```

If some other code elsewhere has already handled an error, how can I stop this handler from also receiving the error?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `global: false` in ajax which has the error handling code.

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    global: false,
    error: function(){},  // Suppresses error message.
    ...
});
```

The local one calls before propagating to global level handler. So you can do something like that

```
var handled=false;

$(document).ajaxError(function (event, request, settings) {
    if(!handled){
        ...
    }
    handled=false;
});
```

Local error handler

```
...
error: function(){if(specificError){handled=true;}},  // Suppresses     error message.
...
```

Comment: I only want to suppress some errors. I want the global handler to act as a catch all for unhandled errors.

Comment: Then i can only think of solution using common variable maintaining the state of error handled or not.

Comment: Its Javascript so I suppose I could add the variable to the error object.