# How would I replace a jQuery ajax error handler

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a global jQuery `ajaxSend` function. It is getting called anytime jQuery performs an ajax request. I am trying (unsuccessfully) to replace the error handler from that function. Here's an example.

```
$(document).ajaxSend( function (event, xhr, obj) {
    xhr.fail = xhr.error = obj.fail = obj.error = function () { 
        alert("hook called"); 
    };
    xhr.abort();
});

$.ajax({ url: window.location.href, error: function () { alert("main called"); }});
```

Here's a fiddle to see what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/a1zh6qtp/

How would I replace the original error handler?

Comment: Probably not, but did you want: [ajaxError](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/)

Comment: thanks for response - the ultimate goal is to remove logic that is set to run in the current error handler, rather than update a lot of client code, I was hoping I could remove or replace it globally

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29449922/2181514

Comment: Looks like the global error handler runs last: https://jsfiddle.net/fa2hp374/

Comment: thanks @freedomn-m - if you can figure out how to prevent that main error handler from being called that's what I'm after :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like jQuery has another global function called `$.ajaxPrefilter()` I am able to replace the original error handler from there.

Here's the updated code:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
  options.fail = originalOptions.fail = jqXHR.fail = 
    options.error = originalOptions.error = jqXHR.error = function () {
      alert("you've been replaced");
    }
});

    
$(document).ajaxSend( function (event, xhr, obj) {
  xhr.abort();
});
  
$.ajax({ url: window.location.href, error: function () { alert("replace me"); }});
```

Here's a fiddle to see it: https://jsfiddle.net/kbnwrj3v/